# wami recoreder with java

Tags: php, javascript, flash, audio

To use wami recorder with java api wich file is needed. I have it's version with flash which contain 
index.html as follow

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<!-- swfobject is a commonly used library to embed Flash content -->
 <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>

 <!-- Setup the recorder interface -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="recorder.js"></script>

 <script>
    function setup() {
            Wami.setup("wami");
    }

    function record() {
          status("Recording...");  
          Wami.startRecording('http://localhost/audiorecording/test.php?name=demo.mp3');

    }

    function play() {   

            Wami.startPlaying("http://localhost/audiorecording/demo.mp3");
            alert("It's start playing");
    }

    function stop() {
            status("");
            Wami.stopRecording();
            alert("stop");
            Wami.stopPlaying();
    }

    function status(msg) {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = msg;
    }
    </script>
     </head>

          <body onload="setup()">
            <input type="button" value="Record" onclick="record()"></input>
                 <input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stop()"></input>
              <input type="button" value="Play" onclick="play()"></input>
              <div id="status"></div>
              <div id="wami"></div>
               </body>
                </html>
```

and one php file as

```
<?php
 parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $params);
  $name = isset($params['name']) ? $params['name'] : 'output.wav';
   $content = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $fh = fopen($name, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $content);
     fclose($fh);
      ?>
```

swfobject.js is available online
and the  other one recoder.js and gui.js is available online

https://wami-recorder.googlecode.com/hg/example/client/index.html

the above thing is done by using flash but it's not working on all pc on click of button  I got error as that  respective function is not available and 
Wami is not defined
Wami.setup("wami");
plz help me out of it or i saw official website of wami where they specify release of 2008 which is java dependent but i am not able to find out how to use it if you have any idea about it so plz reply.......

Comment: recorder.js contain jquery only

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/source/browse/example/client/recorder.js?r=d7925a46e24dd594ab07cb7c3f7364b2d8fd9acd - not seeing any references to jQuery there

Answer (score 0):

Let me first correct a few things:

- Its **JavaScript**, not Java. Javascript is a script language used in browsers, Java is a C# like language used mostly for its compatibility in (hardware)platforms.
- It does **not** depend on jQuery.
- If you want to test on localhost, make sure that there is a server listening with a PHP interpreter (IIS/Apache etc).

Now to answer your "question":

https://wami-recorder.googlecode.com/hg/example/client/index.html this page covers all the basics.

- Include the SWFObject
- Include the recorder.js
- Include the gui.js (!) **You are missing this one**.

It will now find the WAMI.setup function, which is inside [gui.js](https://wami-recorder.googlecode.com/hg/example/client/gui.js).

Now you are good to go :).